# storing data results from stored procedures

Tags: asp.net, stored-procedures, arraylist

I have 2 arraylists. One is principleList which contains integer values that denotes roles (Admin, Project Manager etc.).  Second is codeList which contains the various codes (e.g. AddUserProfile) for which I want to get permissions.  I have a stored procedure "AllowedToPerformFunction" that returns allowed =0 or 1 depending on if a role can perform a code.

I am having trouble with the logic for this since I have multiple ids and multiple codes. For each id, I need to call the stored procedure with each code and store this.
I am trying to store permissions in a hashtable for various roles such as Admin, Project Manager.  So for example for Admin i would need to store:

Admin (id =1) 
code = "AddUser",allowed =1
code="AddProject",allowed=0

hashtable format (key,value) = (1, AddUser-1), (1, AddProject-0)

Here is my code that isn't working:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    getPermissions();
}

void getPermissions()
{
  using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("GoalFishConnectionString")){conn.Open();

    ArrayList idList = getPrincipleIds();
    ArrayList codeList = getCodes();
    ArrayList allowList = new ArrayList();

    for (int i = 0; i < idList.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(idList[i].ToString());

        for (int j = 0; j < codeList.Count; j++)
        {


            MessageBox.Show(codeList[j].ToString());

            SqlCommand command2 = new SqlCommand("AllowedToPerformFunction", conn);
            command2.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command2.Parameters.Clear();
            command2.Parameters.Add("@principalID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idList[i];
            command2.Parameters.Add("@contextID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idList[i];
            command2.Parameters.Add("@roleCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = codeList[j];
            command2.Parameters.Add("@allowed", SqlDbType.Int);
            command2.Parameters["@allowed"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            command2.ExecuteNonQuery();

            int allowed = (int)command2.Parameters["@allowed"].Value;                
            allowList.Add(command2.Parameters["@allowed"].Value);
        }
    }}}

ArrayList getPrincipleIds()
{
    ArrayList principleList = new ArrayList();
         using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("GoalFishConnectionString")){
        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("GetPrinciples", conn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            principleList.Add(rdr["unit_id"]);
        }

        rdr.Close();

  }

    return principleList;
}

ArrayList getCodes()
{
    ArrayList codesList = new ArrayList();
   using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("GoalFishConnectionString")){
        conn.Open();

        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("GetCodes", conn);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            codesList.Add(reader["Code"]);
            //MessageBox.Show(reader["Code"].ToString());
        }

        reader.Close();
    }
   }

    return codesList;
}
```

Any advice or help with this would greatly be appreciated.

Comment: You should wrap your `SqlConnection` construction in a `using` statement.

Comment: This looks like you are going about it in a very wrong way.  Instead, you should pull all of the associations out of the database in a single pass.  If you provide table structures we can give you the query to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not make a class like this and store it in the session?  This way you only have to worry about permissions for one user (unless a user can be admin & Project Manager at the same time)

```
public class LoginUser
{
    public loginUser
    {
        this.Permission = LoadAllPermissions()
    }

    public string Role { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<integer, string> Permission { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this direction. I was able to successfully create a class to store the data like this: public class RolePermissionClass
                    {
                       public ArrayList Permission;
                       public RolePermissionClass()
                        {
                             Permission = new ArrayList();
            }

        }